# How to render a ChoiceField value in a Template?

Tags: django

I'm having trouble getting a ChoiceField value in my template. Here's the form definition (a single radio select field that describes if the product is "fancy" or not):

```
CHOICES = (
    (True, "Yes"),
    (False, "No"),
)

class ProductCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fancy = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=True,
        label="Is this product fancy?",
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
        choices=CHOICES,
        )
```

When I do this in the shell, I'm getting `None`:

```
from django.template import Template, Context
p = Product.objects.first()
form = ProductCreateForm(instance=p)
t = Template("{{ form.fancy.value }}")
c = Context({"form":form})
p.fancy is False
>>> True
print(t.render(c))
>>> None
```

Even if I try to just render the field, none of the radio buttons are selected:

```
t = Template("{{ form.fancy }}")
c = Context({"form":form})
print(t.render(c))
>>> #showing only the two input tags for brevity
>>> <input type="radio" name="basic" value="True" required id="id_basic_0" />
>>> <input type="radio" name="basic" value="False" required id="id_basic_1" />
```

1. Is `{{ form.field.value }}` the right way to get a ChoiceField value out of the form?
2. Why isn't it rendering the radios with the correct `checked` attribute on `{{ form.fancy.1 }}`?

I'm using django 1.11.

Edit: here's an example `Product` class so you can replicate everything in the shell:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    fancy = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Kudos for putting up a minimal reproducable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override what the ModelForm would have added: a ModelChoiceField. The difference with a normal `forms.ChoiceField` is that the choice field gets it's `initial` value from the bound model instance.

If you want to override the widget, then override the widget (using auth's User model as example):

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['is_active', 'is_superuser']
        widgets = {
            'is_active': forms.RadioSelect(choices=((False, 'False'), (True, 'True'))),
        }

>>> str(f['is_active'])  # reformatted
<ul id="id_is_active">
    <li>
        <label for="id_is_active_0">
            <input type="radio" name="is_active" value="False" id="id_is_active_0" />
                False</label>

    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="id_is_active_1">
            <input type="radio" name="is_active" value="True" id="id_is_active_1" checked />
                True</label>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

More info about working with BoundField:

```
>>> u = User.objects.get(id=3)
>>> u.is_active
True
>>> u.is_superuser
False
>>> f = UserForm(instance=u)
>>> f['is_superuser'].value()
False
>>> str(f['is_superuser'])
'<input type="checkbox" name="is_superuser" id="id_is_superuser" />'
>>> str(f['is_active'])
'<ul id="id_is_active">\n    <li><label for="id_is_active_0"><input type="radio" name="is_active" value="False" id="id_is_active_0" />\n Nee</label>\n\n</li>\n    <li><label for="id_is_active_1"><input type="radio" name="is_active" value="True" id="id_is_active_1" checked />\n Ja</label>\n\n</li>\n</ul>'
>>> f['is_active'].value()
True
```

Comment: Melvyn this doesn't address the question at all - I don't care about the label (I can already get that), what I want to know is why the `<input type="radio">` doesn't render with the `checked` attribute, and how to get the value of that field in the template.

Comment: Ooh! You're right. But you're overriding the ModelChoiceField that the model form would've created. Redoing answer.

Comment: Yes, I don't actually want to use a "django template", I want to use my frontend framework to render the template - but I still need some way for the frontend framework to get the field value so that it can be rendered correctly (I don't have a nice completely-decoupled API yet). I would prefer to use the RadioSelect field so that it's consistent, but if for some reason I can't get the value out of django's templater, than I'll change the Widget type to some sort of text field and get it that way.

Comment: As you can see now, value() doesn't care about the widget. Two different widgets, both give the value of the first element of the 2-tuple. In template code field.value will try calling the method if property and dict access fails.